# Not able to call the function with parameter which was exported from other module in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have helper js file which does a common operation. The first js file is been included in my second js file so that the first file operation can be used across.
In file 1, I have a function which accepts a parameter to it and does some operation. I have exported this function to the module. But when I call this function with parameter I get an error as the exported entity is not a function.

```
file1.js
var method = function(parameter){
//   does some operation
}

module.exports.method=method

file2.js
var fileone = require('path to file1')
var f = new fileone()

f.method(test)
```

When in try to invoke f.method(test), I am getting an error as the method is not a function.

Comment: I think you are getting following error `fileone is not a function` instead of `method is not a function`. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Nope, I am getting method is not a function

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, the `new` operator is not required.
Your code should look more like

```
file1.js
var method = function(parameter){
//   does some operation
}

module.exports.method=method

file2.js
var fileone = require('path to file1')

fileone.method(test)
```

Comment: Nope getting the same error @allan. ```Message:
    Failed: fileone.method  is not a function```

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? Also `test` isn't defined.

Comment: yes the path has been resolved.The method takes input in the form of string. Like fileone.method('test') @allan

Comment: Fixed the issue by just using module.exports = method